# How to apply splitted INSIDE border to the video element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

My question is simple & straight forward. I want to apply the splitted INSIDE(not OUTSIDE) border to the Video element.
The below is the simple example of what I want to do:

[image]

In the above pic the black is the video element. The Red-Green is the 2px inside border to the video element.

What I want is apply Red-Green border inside of the video element at any px. I achieved the splitted(Red-Green) border by using `border-image: 'linear-gradient(to right, #39B54A 50%, #FF0000 50%)1'`. I am able to apply the plain single color inside border but not the splitted one. I don't want any work-around like use div element over video element & apply border to that div element.

I am sure their is any way to do this. Thank you!!

**EDIT :**

Here is my code - Currently I am using Div Over Video work-around solution.

```
const video = styled.video`
width:${props => props.width}%;
height:${props => props.videoHeight}%;
margin-left:0%;
margin-top:0%;
position: absolute;`;

const divOverVideo= styled.div`
width:${props => props.width}%;
height: ${props => props.height}%;   
margin-left:${props => props.marginLeft}%;
margin-top:${props => props.marginTop}%;
border: ${props => props.border};
border-image:  ${props => props.borderImage};
position: absolute;
display: ${props => props.display};`;
```

In my HTML code I am calling Div element after the video element.

```
<video {...params} />
<divOverVideo {...params} />
```

Comment: so it should overlap the video?

Comment: Yes it overlaps.

Comment: share the code if the video so we can see the structure you are using

Comment: right now I am doing it with the work-around solution. I have div over video element and apply border to the div element. But don't like this way. If the solution has too much changes for me then, I open to do it.

Comment: we still need to see your HTML code and how you are using the video (iframe, video tag, etc)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I have added my code in question.